# Activity flow in android

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, intentfilter

Sorry if this question has been asked before . What I am trying to do is when app starts splash screen appear and after 3 second My `mainactivity` runs . but when I press back button it returns me again on splash screen . So my question is how can I control the flow of activity so that it should not come again to `splash screen` below is my

```
manifest file 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And if there are lots of activity and i want my mainactivity to be parent activity and if user is on parent activity and user press back then splash screen should not appear . Is there a way to do that through manifest

Comment: finish your activity

Comment: call this.finsh() after you call startActivity(intent) in spash Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Simplest solution is: set **android:noHistory="true"** in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
          android:noHistory="true" 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: android:noHistory="true" do this attribute will destroy my splashscreen activity?

Comment: Yes, definitely. It will not be visible again after pressing back from another activity. But will be seen every time you launch app

Answer (score 5):

You have to finish SplashActivity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

just finish you splash activity when you move to main activity.

```
               // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `finish()` as soon as you are done displaying your Splash screen, then on pressing Back Button it won't return to your previous activity.

> **finish ()**:
>   Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

code snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make your `Intent` to your `MainActivity`, after `startActivity(intent)`, write `finish();`

Answer (score 0):

When you are Traversing to `MainActivity` through intent finish your `SplashActivity` there like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

@FaisalAhmed

In your mainActivity override method `onBackPressed()` where you finish your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in SplashScreen override menthod onStop:

```
@Override
 public void onStop() {
     finish();
    }
```

When you click back button in MainAcyivity then application will exit.
Besides, you can handle on menthod onBackPressed MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (yourLayout.canGoBack()) {
        yourlayout.goBack();
    } 
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```